# Supporting multiple params in get request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing out a small analytics project. For this I want to be able to have a get method on a controller which can take a lot of parameters.

This means that the url could be:
www.mydomain.com/event?browser=x&url=www.mydomain.com&someotherparam=test&anotherparam=test2

How can change routing in a Get action for a controller to support this URL structure instead of the traditional "event/:id"?

currently my routes.rb file looks like this:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  #

  root 'home#index'
  namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      #resources :event_queue, :to => :event
      #resources :event#, :controller => :event
        get '/event/' => 'event#get'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Everything after the `event?` is optional. How do your routes look like?

Comment: I am a bit rusty, so I am just testing it and it (almost) only contains get '/event/' => 'event#get'. You are correct all params are optional.

Comment: Are you using a path helper to generate `/event`? If so, just pass a hash into your path helper and it will generate additional query parameters.

Answer (score 3):

you can send as many params as you want, it is called query params, all of these params after '?' are optional.

Comment: http:example.com/some_route?param1=value1&param2=value2

Comment: Edit: you have limited length in GET Request

https://helpx.adobe.com/mt/experience-manager/scene7/kb/base/is_protocol-_-forming_is/url-character-limit-get-requests.html